# How to Go to New Screen/Page in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I have a quick question regarding Android Studio.

So First Of all I am COMPLETELY new to this thing so don't get me wrong if i make a mistake.

So what I am doing is that I have created a title screen for my app called "Canada Quiz". And below the title I have a "Start" Button. And what I done so far is I have attached a code that would do something like this: So once a Start Button is clicked it would hide it. Now my Question.

How would I make it so That once Clicked it should hide the Start Button and show the Question and a TRUE and FALSE button. All I have is this. I just want the Questions the appear as soon as the person taps the Start Button. And in My Content_Main.xml i have a phone as a model witch displays the start button and the Canada quiz. So Please help me out as soon as POSSIBLE

Thank you!

```
package com.example.nilesh.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button startButton;
    private Button trueButton;
    private Button falseButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        ArrayList <String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();

        String firstQue = " Is Canada Located in North America? ";
        String secondQue = " Is Ontario the Largest provice in Canada? ";
        String thridQue = " Is Toronto the Largest City in Canada? ";
        String fourQue = " Canada has 3 professional Basketball Teams. ";
        String fiveQue = " Canada has 11 Provinces and 3 Territories. ";
        String sixQue = " Justin Trudeau is not Canada's Prime Minister. ";

        final String [] allQuestions = {firstQue,secondQue,thridQue,fourQue,fiveQue,sixQue};


        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View v) {
                startButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public Button getTrueButton() {
        return trueButton;
    }

    public void setTrueButton(Button trueButton) {
        this.trueButton = trueButton;
    }

    public Button getFalseButton() {
        return falseButton;
    }

    public void setFalseButton(Button falseButton) {
        this.falseButton = falseButton;
    }
}
```

**Note** I cannot see the TRUE BUTTON and FALSE BUTTON the content_main.xml file....

Comment: You should first learn about activities and than how to start one activity from other activity... This is very basic thing in Android...

Comment: Read through the android developers [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go to next screen, use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
```